# How can I load unicode text in richtextbox c# without any blank column?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I use this code for set text to richtextbox :

```
DarolhodaCl.Properties Db = new DarolhodaCl.Properties();
Rtb_Editor.Text = Db.GetPropertyContent(TextFileIdentity);

[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
        public String GetPropertyContent(Int32 PropertyId)
        {
            String Content = null;
            object[] values = new object[] { PropertyId };
            using (IDataReader Idr = Db.ExecuteReader("spGetPropertyContent", values))
            {
                if (Idr.Read())
                {
                    Content = FieldUtil.GetString(Idr["PropertyContent"]);
                }
            }
            return Content;
        }
```

Data save in database with nvarchar(max) data type. I store a text of word file in this column.

Please see this image :
[image]

When I use persian text(unicode) in rtl richtextbox, I see a blank white column in right of richtext box. How can i fill text in richtext box full or no see this column ?

Comment: Screenshots are an incredibly lousy way to troubleshoot problems with code.  Random guess: set the RichTextBox.RightMargin property back to 0, it doesn't work correctly for RTL layout.

Comment: Show the code that sets the rtf and part of the resulting rtf

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the following code snippet and didn't get the same result as you did. Show your code please.

```
    String test = "سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام سلام ";

    richTextBox1.Text = test;
```

You're most probably doing something like this:

```
String test = @"
                سلام سلام سلام سلام
                سلام سلام سلام سلام
                سلام سلام سلام سلام 
                ";

richTextBox1.Text = test;
```

The space characters behind each line **counts**! You should delete those spaces

Comment: I updated my photo. I select all text and In image you can see text data no have any spaces in first of lines.

Comment: There's got to be something wrong with the answer of the query you're trying to execute on your DB. Have you traced the code with the debugger (`F10` and so) ?